# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $\sqrt{1+a/s}$?

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

My question is that, what is the inverse Laplace transform of $\sqrt{1+a/s}$  where $a \gt 0$?

I tried to find solution in the Integral and Series books, but failed.

Comment: Enclose your formulas between two dollar signs "$" to have the formula properly written

Comment: The problem is finding the inverse transform of $F(s)=\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{s}}, a>0$? or does the problem have some additional context? The context of a problem and knowing your attempts, progress and tools that you know can help us to help you with solutions that are understandable to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "solution from a book" uses [modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1): $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\sqrt{1+2a/s}-1\right](t)=ae^{-at}\big(I_0(at)+I_1(at)\big)$$ (easily obtained from the LT of $I_\alpha$; should I find a reference to the latter?..).

Knowing the ILT of $1$ (the first entry of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms#Table)), you're done.